# No such file or directory in

Tags: php, android

I am doing an application for android and i need to upload to the server the profile picture of user i try to do it by ftp , but wen i send the path from android app of this picture it give me an error , and i dont understand much about path from android to web , what i do wrong?
Also forgot to coment i do a random strind with `uniqid();` for the name of the file uploaded.
This is my error:

> ftp_put(/storage/emulated/0/Download/red-bull-2384130__480.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/nicetaxi/public_html/mobilapp/uploadfile.php on line 18
> This is my code

```
<?php

$ftp_server="ftp.......";
$ftp_user_name="......";
$ftp_user_pass=".......";
$Random_str = uniqid();
$file = $_POST["path"];
echo $file;
$remote_file = $Random_str . ".jpg";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
exit;
} else {
echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
exit;
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: Provide Correct Path of file

Comment: Where is this php script executed? On an Android device? Or on a server on the internet? Is your Android app calling this script? And the ftp server is running where? On the internet? And would that be a different server as the php server?

Comment: Do you have an upload form where users can pick a file to upload? If so, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

> > ftp_put(/storage/emulated/0/Download/red-bull-2384130__480.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/nicetaxi/public_html/mobilapp/uploadfile.php on line 18

Your server is on the internet and you posted a file path for a file residing on your Android device.

Sorry, but that server connot access files on your Android device.

It does not even try as php thinks its a path on the server itself.

Well then it will not find it.

Instead you should post the file itself to to php server.